# Liquibase generateChangeLog Ant task diffTypes

Tags: liquibase

The difftypes="data" attribute in generateChangeLog ant task works with liquibase 3.2.2 but does not seem to  work with liquibase 3.3.2

```
<generateChangeLog
       ....
      difftypes="data"  />
```

According to liquibase doc : 
It seems that syntax has changed and that I should use includeObjects.
But when i'm trying

```
<generateChangeLog
       ....
      includeObjects="data:mytable"  />
```

The generated files is empty

What is the right syntax to generate **a data** changelog using liquibase version >= 3.3.2 ?

Comment: Have you tried using both attributes at the same time? i.e. both diffTypes="data" AND includeObjects="data:myTable" ?

Comment: unfortunately yes ... the message i get with liquibase 3.3.2 is "generateChangeLog doesn't support the "diffTypes" attribute